# How to get data element of checkbox on change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I've got a dynamic table of items with checkboxes next to each item. When a user selects a checkbox I want to grab the "Name" item from the table and add it to a textbox. See image:

[image]

The way I'm trying to accomplish this is by adding a "change" event to every checkbox and populating it's "data-name" element with the name of the text.

```html
<tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="selectBox" data-name="@item.Name" /></td>
```

As you can see I'm populating data-name with the item name as a way to get around pulling it directly (which I don't know how to do). Now in javascript/jquery I'm tying an event to every checkbox and attempting to get the data element using the following code:

```html
$('input[name=selectBox]').change(function (item) {
    var text = $(item).attr('data-name');
});
```

When the code runs the event is firing for all checkboxes, but "text" is undefined when I expect it to be the name data.

Looking for an answer to my method of doing this AND/OR a better way involving skipping the data element all together and getting the name value directly. Thanks for looking.

Comment: As long as you don't dump the whole view-model to the client (like in Single Page Applications), the common way to associate arbitrary data from the model with some elements is indeed the `data-*` attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var text = $(this).data('name');
```

The first parameter of your `change` function is the `event`, not the element itself. Also, jQuery automatically sets the function scope (`this`) to the element being changed.

See [Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/change/)

Comment: Oh man.... $(this) instead of $(item). How simple. Thanks, this worked like a charm. If anyone knows how to do this without using data element I'd be interested to see that as well. Thanks - I'll accept this answer in 10 mins when SO lets me

Answer (score 3):

In your case `item` is event object not `DomElement`, you can get element through event property [`currentTarget`](https://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/)

```
$('input[name=selectBox]').change(function (item) {
    var text = $(item.currentTarget).attr('data-name'); 
});
```

or use `this` because `this` refer` on *current Element*, it is the same as in previous example but shorter

```
$('input[name=selectBox]').change(function (item) {
    var text = $(this).attr('data-name'); 
});
```